# React mutate state before passing props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is there any way to change state first before passing props from state to its children component in react? Here is an example:

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
    let parsedKeyword = queryString.parse(nextProps.location.search).q;

    if (parsedKeyword !== prevState.keyword) {

        return {
            keyword: parsedKeyword,
        }

    }

    return {
        keyword: prevState.keyword,
    };
}

render() {
    return ( 
       <ChildComponent myProps={this.state.keyword} />
    );
}
```

In my case, I want react to change the keyword state immediately when receiving `nextProps` before passing props to `ChildComponent`. How can i do it in react?

Answer (score 1):

You can modify it before return statement inside `getDerivedStateFromProps`.

Alternatively you can manipulate in render, before passing to ChildComponent, it doesn't change the state though.

```
render() {
  const modifiedKeyword = this.state.keyword + 'Modified'
  return (
    <ChildComponent myProps={modifiedKeyword}/>
  );

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are using the latest version of React (v16.3.2).

The [React Blog](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/27/update-on-async-rendering.html#initializing-state) suggests you should initialize state in your constructor. According to the [React Doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops), `getDerivedStateFromProps` is called after component initialization, and again when new props are received.